# R star plot smaller unit.key

Tags: r, data-visualization

The following command will generate a star plot,

```
stars(mtcars[, 1:7], key.loc = c(14, 1.5), main = "Motor Trend Cars : full stars()")
```

how to make the unit key(bottom right corner) smaller or bigger?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand properly, you want to increase the key polygon leaving the same size of the data polygons. Unfortunatelly, it is not possible. If we look at the source code of the `stars()` function, we will establish that the size of the both data and key polygons is controlled by the same argument `len`.

However, you may write you own modified `stars()` function making that possible. One way is to add an additional argument for the the key expansion, and define a separate length argument for the legend

```
stars2 <- function (x, key.exp = 1, .....)
{
    key_expansion <- key.exp
    len_legend <- key_expansion * len
    ...
}
```

Then the new length argument `len_legend` should be applied to draw the key instead of the old `len` argument. Thaht is, `len` should be replaced by `len_legend` inside the code  which draws the key unit (the whole code chunk inside the `if (!is.null(key.loc)) { .... }` statement), like this:

```
   if (!is.null(key.loc)) {
        par(xpd = key.xpd)
        key.x <- len_legend * cos(angles) + key.loc[1L]
        key.y <- len_legend * sin(angles) + key.loc[2L]
       ...
   }
```

Let's check the results:

```
pdf("res_stars.pdf")
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
    stars(mtcars[, 1:7], 
        key.loc = c(14, 1.5), 
        main = "Motor Trend Cars : full stars()",
        cex = 0.3)
    stars2(mtcars[, 1:7], 
        key_expansion = 1.3,
        key.loc = c(14, 1.5), 
        main = "Motor Trend Cars : full stars()",
        cex = 0.3)
dev.off()
```

[image]